# Is the king in check?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, chess

**Challenge:**
Given a 2D array (8x8) of characters, is the enemy king in check?
The program should return true **if and only if** the king is **currently** in check.
Standard chess rules apply.

**Specifications**:
The game is provided using a 2D array,
where blank space means there is not a piece on that square.
You may assume that the only characters that will appear 
in the array are one of: `[SPACE]kpnbrqKPNBRQ`

The 2D array is given as a y-major array
that starts from the bottom left (a1 square), 
which means accessing the array would be: `board[row][column]`.
For example: `board[0][0] is a1`, and `board[3][5] is f4`

Character set: 
King - `K`
Pawn - `P`
Knight - `N`
Bishop - `B`
Rook - `R`
Queen - `Q`

Your own pieces are in uppercase, and the enemy pieces are in lowercase.
Also, enemy pieces only serve the purpose of blocking a check, so they are essentially the same as pawns.

**Test case:**
[image: Game 1]
In this game, the given array would be:

```
r bqk  r
p pp Bpp
 pn  n  
    p  Q
 b PP   
  P     
PP   PPP
RNB K NR
```

and should return true. Note that even if the bishop on f7 wasn't protected, it should still return true.

Happy golfing!

Comment: Related: [Is it checkmate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/190898/is-it-checkmate).

Comment: Why this input instead of FEN?

Comment: @qwr I think this input needs a lot less explanation (and possibly less code) than Forsyth Edwards Notation, which is generally known only by chess fans.

Comment: Because the board orientation matters for pawn moves, I think you should clarify how the black and white pieces are arranged, rather than just mentioning _your own pieces_ and _enemy pieces_.

Comment: @Arnauld It is specified that the a1 square is the first entry of the array. I thought it would've implied the orientation of the board.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 95 bytes

```
≔⪫ＥθＳ¶η¿⊙⌕ＡηN⁼⁵ΣＸ⟦⁻÷ι⁹÷⌕ηk⁹⁻﹪ι⁹﹪⌕ηk⁹⟧²-«Ｐη…η⌕ηk≔Ｅ⁸ＫＤ⁹✳ιζ⎚∨⊙✂ζ⁵χ²⁼§ι¹P⊙ζ№⊞Ｏ⟦Q⟧§RBκ§Φι⊙…ι⊕μ∧π⁻ ν¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNb9swDIbP9a8gdKIBFWgGDFjQUz4WIBuSqMmx28GxtZiIIimynK0d9ts90UmaAhUMyKT4viSfsi5C6QrTdaOmoZ3Fb44sLgqPRwlz69u4iYHsDvNcgvhhRbrq/DGjX4Aj@4IzstXIGKzT65Ifvx7bwjT4WcKmPaByv3XA5wXZtsG5jVM6UaWRJAxz9r8m2Kb32LPHkJudNQtXtcZdBZfoQ/VPCZ9yPqDSsBHFvUgzatNo@JvdLVoTyfcPPPrduWbyUho9qZ1np/eOOddcaDCILxKU1vspBV1GchaHEm4B5TzsK2smRhcBbx1WoUe0MVRqfJWQmAweeNI3SqM4t5X@w@sNmK8SbMaiVD5xbTJRbVOvvA5FdAmkeBJp16tMrMdCwr7XXFIzMjERp7PLbUdi2mXQB22jrvBw7lOhv4IWkKxs3m8z6Fk@Zv@6LsD2uAcImQfvYex9Bt4CpC@DdDzAUwZbUAr6DF/ppw@VUtl6OYbvsFx39yfzHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for in check, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
≔⪫ＥθＳ¶η
```

Input the board and join it on newlines.

```
¿⊙⌕ＡηN⁼⁵ΣＸ⟦⁻÷ι⁹÷⌕ηk⁹⁻﹪ι⁹﹪⌕ηk⁹⟧²-«
```

If there is a knight a knight's move away from the king, then output a `-`, otherwise:

```
Ｐη…η⌕ηk≔Ｅ⁸ＫＤ⁹✳ιζ⎚
```

Temporarily write the board to the canvas so that all of the ranks, files and diagonals to the king can be extracted.

```
∨⊙✂ζ⁵χ²⁼§ι¹P⊙ζ№⊞Ｏ⟦Q⟧§RBκ§Φι⊙…ι⊕μ∧π⁻ ν¹
```

Check for pawns that are checking the king and check the first piece in every direction for a piece that can check the king from that direction.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 188 bytes

Expects a matrix of characters and returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
f=(m,P,X,Y)=>m.some((r,y)=>r.some((p,x)=>P?{N:(H=x-X,H*=H)+(v=y-Y)*v-5,B:B=H-v*v|(g=A=>u=(c=m[A+=-(A>Y)|A<Y][x+=-(x>X)|x<X])!=P&&c>g|g(A))(y),R:u|=H*=v,Q:B*u,P:H-1}[p]+P=='0k':f(m,p,x,y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5db4IwFEDf@RV3PmiLhbiHvTAvCyRbSJaYqi8Q5QERGJOPWpBgxN/uqluypEl7bk5vznfURU0sc9EaVb1PbrcUSck481lA0S7Npi4TQiQ7K5J/JFiviL9dFhbxsDd85uno0Snp8GwEVO@MF@ZaLnpGp3cDydBB@4QkxnLjTNEgjh3QwZkH4aa/Y2/7dOjnfkifkI/HsZ0NGXEoJWfKVtZpQLW9Y0vL1U@MW57xfN2IcMoRJ7PDxEpVrgpSgZTeZHI85TIho7QZUVMm0f4jL5L1uYrJjJptvW5lXmWEmo0o8paMttW2UmJay/co/iINoA0XDaBIWigBofkXlVZG4lfZmKbZhPRVmXFdNXWRmEWdEZVC1fCqOmB3PABITYAQ4AqhgagA1FFfAATAUoMdcA6Pyf1SjwdyzrXVwoVPWKx@AA)

### Position editor

```js
f=(m,P,X,Y)=>m.some((r,y)=>r.some((p,x)=>P?{N:(H=x-X,H*=H)+(v=y-Y)*v-5,B:B=H-v*v|(g=A=>u=(c=m[A+=-(A>Y)|A<Y][x+=-(x>X)|x<X])!=P&&c>g|g(A))(y),R:u|=H*=v,Q:B*u,P:H-1}[p]+P=='0k':f(m,p,x,y)))
let board = document.getElementById("board"), pce = document.getElementById("pce"), b = [...Array(8)].map(_ => Array(8).fill(-1)), sel = 5; b[1][2] = 6; b[2][4] = 4; setClick(board, (x, y) => { b[y][x] = b[y][x] == sel ? -1 : sel; draw(); }); setClick(pce, (x, y) => { sel = x * 6 + 5 - y; draw(); }); draw(); function setClick(el, callback) { el.addEventListener("click", e => { let o = el.getBoundingClientRect(); callback(e.clientX - o.left >> 5, e.clientY - o.top >> 5); }) } function draw() { let html = "", m = []; for(let y = 0; y < 8; y++) for(let x = 0; x < 8; x++) { html += `<div class="sq ${x + y & 1 ? "dark" : "light"}">${~b[y][x] ? `&#${9812 + b[y][x]};` : ""}</div>`; (m[y] = m[y] || [])[x] = " KQRBNPkqrbnp"[b[y][x] + 1]; } document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = f(m) ? "YES" : "NO"; board.innerHTML = html; html = ""; for(let y = 0; y < 6; y++) for(let x = 0; x < 2; x++) html += `<div class="sq ${x * 6 + 5 - y == sel ? "sel" : x + y & 1 ? "dark" : "light"}">&#${9817 + x * 6 - y};</div>`; pce.innerHTML = html; }
```

```css
body { font-family:Arial; } #board { float:left; width:256px; height:256px; } #pce { float:left; margin-left:32px; width:64px; height:192px; } .sq { float:left; width:32px; height:32px; line-height:32px; text-align:center; font-size:30px; cursor:pointer; } .dark { background-color:#7ab; } .light { background-color:#9cd; } .sel { background-color:#fd4; }
```

```html
<p>Black king in check: <span id="res"></span></p><div id="board"></div><div id="pce"></div>
```

### Commented

#### Main function

```javascript
f = (               // f is a recursive function taking:
  m,                //   m[] = input matrix
  P,                //   P = piece on the target square
  X, Y              //   (X, Y) = position of the target square
) =>                //
m.some((r, y) =>    // for each row r[] at index y in m[]:
  r.some((p, x) =>  //   for each piece p at index x in r[]:
    P ?             //     if P is defined (2nd pass):
      {             //
        N: ...,     //       \    test whether the target square is
        B: ...,     //        |   attacked by the source square (x, y)
        R: ...,     //        |-- according to the piece p
        Q: ...,     //        |   these tests (which are detailed below)
        P: ...      //       /    return 0 for truthy
      }[p]          //
      + P           //       append P to the result
      == '0k'       //       if we get '0k', the enemy king is attacked
    :               //     else (1st pass):
      f(m, p, x, y) //       do a recursive call, using the current
                    //       square as the target square
  )                 //   end of inner some()
)                   // end of outer some()
```

#### Knight test

```javascript
(                   // define:
  H = x - X,        //   H = (x - X)²
  H *= H            //
) + (               // and:
  v = y - Y         //   v = y - Y
) * v               //
- 5                 // test whether H + v² = 5, which may only happen
                    // if we have H = 4, v² = 1 or H = 1, v² = 4
```

#### Bishop test

```javascript
B =                 // save the result in B
H - v * v |         // we must have H = v²
( g = A =>          // g is a recursive function
  u =               // which sets a flag u if the path from the source
  (                 // square to the target square is blocked:
    c =             //   c is the value of the square that is reached
    m[              //   when we move towards the target square
      A += -(A > Y) //   by adding the sign of Y - A to A
           | A < Y  //
    ][              //   
      x += -(x > X) //   and adding the sign of X - x to x
           | x < X  //
    ]               //
  ) != P &&         //   stop when c = P
  c > g |           //   set u if c is greater than or equal to 'B'
                    //   (i.e. the square is not empty)
  g(A)              //   recursive call
)(y)                // initial call to g with A = y
```

#### Rook test

```javascript
u |= H *= v         // we must have u = 0 and either H = 0 or v = 0
```

#### Queen test

```javascript
B * u               // queen = bishop * rook
```

#### Pawn test

```javascript
H - 1               // we must have (x - X)² = 1 and y - Y = 1
                    // and H is now (x - X)² * (y - Y)
```

#### King test

Assuming that the position is valid, a king may not be attacked by the other king. Therefore, there is no test at all for king attacks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>192 170 167</s> 166 bytes

```ruby
->s{z=!k=/k/=~s+=$/*9
72.times{|i|i%8<1?(C=D=i/8%3+i/24*9-10;J=k):" "!=W&&D=0
z||="RQBP"[~C%2,C/8>i%16?3:2]=~/#{W=s[J+=D]}/||s[i]*((i%9-k%9)*(i/9-k/9))**2==?N*4}
!!z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFLb@IwEL77VwxOUyXhYZIilrTrIgE9bFdiA2XVQ5RDCE6x0gYTh5ZC4K@zea26hx3Z45nP8/jGTnbLz0tIL@17eTzQRkRJROhZNukVMWz0zeqk/I3JY8Yzrg6@m0NtTCeUk4F60@TE6hl22@zePdJIv8WAG/T5@npCu@iQZRTPZyMHu@exarXGZHDPVbM/vLm1PHomyvGZSvexSSfeiWSZdLlnaBpX7Xak2rqhcZJbxNZ1w7AoHU6N3gk1GofTRUDo4gSW2wggQQKEgJEQCEQMkC8EuQiAGYIlOA6USHHkRuk6joPm0xH8hOkcYQ@JXSoBa78cSJlMA18yHSGMkLJ4eFrA0@8fiwekhJsEfAj5nq1gufGTVQs27yz5SHjKwH99hX4P5HbnJ0yCxvYBEymkawabON9BsBO8SPwssYjHLzp88HRdulKwgIfFfR4U5NXiVcmkg8pGXYqhFgQJQAT1jPBlCCiG/UK2/4nJDYyK1rQq2@Hxiu21YaSjfu/vF5cMKk1LbdhkUPEw6zzDvKt8twzwKJ5hJVj78QuDt8173qCeY80SVj@uUgtuVamtf5DQrTCvdUWAh1VygxZMT5c/)

Function taking a newline separated string as an argument. See [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/15599) for discussion of equivalence of strings and arrays, and use of sentinel values as separators/terminators. A final newline is required (It would cost 1 byte `$/*9`->`$/*10` to remove this requirement.) The two `!!` at the end ensure a clean true/false value is returned. Deleting them would save 2 bytes but return only a truthy/falsy output.

**Explanation**

Take a 72-character argument consisting of 8 lines each of 9 characters including the final newline. Add 9 newlines `$/`to the end. The newlines will act as non-space characters and prevent scanning from circling round to the other side of the board. Assign `k` to the index of the king by regex `/k/`. Assign `false=!k` to `z`. Iterate 72 times (scan up to 8 squares from the king in 9 possible directions. Simultaneously scan all 72 characters for knights.)

```ruby
->s{z=!k=/k/=~s+=$/*9
72.times{|i|
```

If `i%8==0` set `J` to the location of the king and select a new direction `C=D` to scan in. Offsets for horizontal scanning are `i/8%3-1=[-1,0,1]` Offsets for vertical scanning are `i/8/3*9-9=[-9,0,9]`. Combining these gives diagonal scanning `+/-10` and `+/-8`. `0+0=0` is also generated as a ninth possible offset but makes no difference to the result. If `i%8>0` check if the last character scanned `W` was a space, and if not set `D=0` to prevent further scanning in that direction.

```ruby
i%8<1?(C=D=i/8%3+i/24*9-10;J=k):" "!=W&&D=0
```

Check the character at `s[J+=D]` advancing `J` in direction `D`. Depending on the value of `C` select the values of character that would threaten the king. Where `C` is odd `+/-1`,`+/-9` they start at index 0: `RQ`. Where `C` is even `+/-8`,`+/-10` they start at index 1: `QBP`. Pawns should only be checked for on the first step in a diagonal direction `i%16=0` and where the `y` direction is positive `C/8>0`.

```ruby
z||="RQBP"[~C%2,C/8>i%16?3:2]=~/#{W=s[J+=D]}/
```

Check also for knights, which threaten the king on squares `s[i]` where `(i%9-k%9)*(i/9-k/9)` is `+/-2`. Squaring this gives `4`. We take the character at `s[i]` and multiply by the numerical value giving a string of identical characters, then check if equal to the string `?N*4="NNNN"`. This is fewer bytes than separate string and numerical checks.

```ruby
||s[i]*((i%9-k%9)*(i/9-k/9))**2==?N*4
```

Close the iteration loop and clean up the final value `z` from truthy/falsy to true/false by inverting twice.

```ruby
}
!!z}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 258 bytes

I thought I'd try my own challenge cuz why not. It's not terrible but it could be better. I'll try to post an explanation when I have time.

Takes a 2D array (just like the challenge description).

```python
f=lambda b:any(['PN'[(p:=z-60)>0]in(g:=f"{(' '*16).join(map(''.join,b)):^576}")[(k:=g.find('k'))-p]+(p>0)*g[k+p]for z in b'%#mkVR']+[((t:=g[k-8*n:k+8*n:n])[9+(i<0)*i:8+(i>0)*i].split()==[])*(t[i+8]in'RBQQ'[n<0::2])for n in[1,24,-23,-25]for i in range(-8,8)])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=pairmap`, <s>316</s> 286 bytes

```perl
sub{map{map{($r,$c)=($t,$_)if($l=$_[$t][$_])eq'k';push@n,$t,$_ if'N'eq$l}0..7;++$t}@_;map{$v.=$_[$u=$r+$_][$c];$x.=$c+$_>=0&&$_[$u][$c+$_];$y.=$c-$_>=0&&$_[$u][$c-$_];}-$r..7-$r;(pairgrep{abs(($r-$a)*($c-$b))==2}@n)|(grep/[QR] *k|k *[QR]/,$v,"@{$_[$r]}")|grep/kP|[QB] *k|k *[QB]/,$x,$y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBta4MwEMff@ymOclTT@rRBGTRLkb7dVqywVyKiRVvR2TTarqX61ecSxxgskNzD73@XXHgmqsWAORuac3r/SPi4DRQm7ggzsDUxJkVuYMUwDrGNQowjkp30Uqf83By82hw1UOT6Rs9OWPWubT/R@Rzb3oup6oYXeyw@MxRzWR7iLqJ4lcmdDFfMnU5HrIDiFG@KWf@ZpVhvoZAXyJMaPCnEXmT8nqSNId9sYUJmhhKmhDD22Hs16QylcMJtEMGs7EqYKdcx8WJOvLvqLaJ@QrpRVfpduF3/CddKeDXx1g8/0yZm6NjOPvo8FFX2vKJNcgO3m2JueAmhg4D0VAJshMaBcwg414DXABmABnJxgK0GKfg@jBllpDOGvu9rwWYNL7AJvo68LY51M1hvC9t9cKV9LZp2uXxvi4qpseW/mr/jD1b1DQ)